# Can you run a Maven plugin only once on build success?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin that I want to run only once after built success, so that:

1. If I am building just a single sub module, then the plugin also runs at the end after the sub module is built.
2. If I am building from the parent, the plugin is executed at the end after all the sub modules are built, not every time after a sub module is built.

Prefer an answer that only requires proper pom setup to execute an existing maven plugin. Only if this is not solvable via pom settings, then I pick an answer that shows how to write a custom plugin like this in java.

Comment: and what is it in the plugin that you want to execute it not per module but a complete reactor build?

Comment: First what kind of action should this plugin handle?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Don't know. I have no plan yet. But why does that matter? Are you trying to think of some alternatives to achieve the same effect? If that's the case, I shall add that no alternatives are accepted as answer. Otherwise why does it matter what I am planning to do with the plugin? But obviously, some batch operations on newly packaged jars.

Comment: @user1589188 If I were you, I would try to be more open. If khmarbaise has a good "alternative", I would surely consider it.

Comment: @user1589188 First I try to understand the real problem which are you trying to solve. If you don't like give information about it what the problem is or what you are trying to do I can't make good suggestions how to solve the problem..maybe the problems have already been solved in other ways or you might not fully understand the concept of Maven etc....Furthermore you wrote: "obviously , some batch operations..." To be honest what is "obviously" here? What kind of operation is need to do on already build jars ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I mean if I am asking for a solution rather than an answer to a particular question, then it would be too open to be qualified on SO. My goal here is to find a way to run maven plugin in the way I have described, not anything in particular that the maven plugin has to do. Like a proof of concept. Only after that, I will see what I can do about it. The "obvious" part was linking to the fact that it has to be run after jars are built, not before, not in the middle, so something to do with them in one go. An immediate example like printing a combined hash of all the jars